# Option to upload and download file to SharePoint Document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, client-object-model

I want to give option to user on `.aspx` page to upload and download file to SharePoint Document library.

I created an ASPX form page. There is an option to upload / download the document for storage.

My requirement is,

- I need both upload and download button in the same page.
- While clicking the upload from the `.aspx` page the document should store in SharePoint 2010 document library.
- While clicking download from .aspx page it should download from the document library, using the document library for Document storage.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is hosted inn sharepoint, You can use server object model for this

If it is hosted outside, you can use client object model:

```
public void UploadDocument(string siteURL, string documentListName,
string documentListURL, string documentName,

byte[] documentStream)
{

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
{        

//Get Document List
List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentListName);

var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
//Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream

fileCreationInformation.Content = documentStream;
//Allow owerwrite of document

fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
//Upload URL

fileCreationInformation.Url = siteURL + documentListURL + documentName;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
    fileCreationInformation);

//Update the metadata for a field having name "DocType"
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["DocType"] = "Favourites";

uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
}

public Stream DownloadDocument(string siteURL, string documentName)
{

ListItem item = GetDocumentFromSP(documentName);
if (item != null)

{
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))

{
FileInformation fInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext,
    item ["FileRef"].ToString());            

return fInfo.Stream;
}

}
return null;

}


private static ListItem GetDocumentFromSP(string documentName)
{

//This method is discussed above i.e. Get List Item Collection from SharePoint
//Document List
ListItemCollection listItems = GetListItemCollectionFromSP("FileLeafRef", 
    documentName, "Text", 1);


return (listItems != null && listItems.Count == 1) ? listItems[0] : null;

}
```

Comment: hi Aanchal, its hosted outside...

Comment: So, you can use above code and use CSOM.